# SignalR with ASP.NET MVC and WinForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that includes functions invoked via SignalR. The ASP.NET application works fine and the data is updated for all clients in real time.

Can I create a WinForms application and connect to the same SignalR application and push data to my web applications through it? If so how can I connect to my SignalR Asp.NET MVC application through WinForms.

Comment: [official documentation's code sample for winforms.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure! You can use the SignalR client to connect to the server running inside your ASP.NET application.

Check [this](http://ruchirac.blogspot.it/2013/03/connecting-net-client-console.html) for a full sample with a Console application (but it's the same for Winforms).

You need to use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs` than you can create a connection like this:

```
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:53748");
    var chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

    chat.On<string, string>("broadcastMessage", (name, message) => { Console.Write(name + ": "); Console.WriteLine(message); });

    hubConnection.Start().Wait();
    chat.Invoke("Notify", "Console app", hubConnection.ConnectionId);
```

Comment: THanks, so if my web application is running on http://localhost:59842, my signalR app will have the same address? Or I have to define an address for my signalR app?

Comment: The signalr server is hosted inside your mvc app, usually under /signalr path; in this case, you need to use only the root url (without the /signalr section).